# Oracle ORA Errors evaluation order

Tags: sql, oracle, error-handling

Regarding the ORA error codes, can I assume they are evaluated in ascending order?

Let's say I got error ORA-01031. In this case, does it mean that all other possible errors whose code is less than 1031 (ORA-00904 for example) were successfully overcome?

Comment: No, every error code is unique. There is no correlation between them. Each place in Oracle's internal code where an error condition might arise is instrumented to catch that situation and throw whatever number that situation warrants. I'm sure there *is* an order of parsing evaluation but as far as I know it isn't published. Experiment and find out :)

Answer (score 4):

No. As a trivial example of that not being the case:

```
select no_such_column from no_such_table;
```

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

```
select no_such_column from dual;
```

```
ORA-00904: "NO_SUCH_COLUMN": invalid identifier
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6fU7M6be)

Fixing the ORA-00942 revealed an ORA-00904, which is a lower number.

Oracle decides how and in what order to evaluate a query or update or anonymous block, and will throw whatever error is appropriate when it finds one. It doesn't go through in error number order. There is no particular relevance to the error numbers.